# Vue.js adding local javascript file to head section of HTML document in index.html

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to add a local file to the HEAD section of index.html in my VueJs project.

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- https://npms.io/search?q=vue%20split -->
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

      <!-- Load required Bootstrap and BootstrapVue CSS -->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />

      <!-- Load polyfills to support older browsers -->
      <script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CMutationObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <!-- Load Vue followed by BootstrapVue -->
      <script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

      <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../src/assets/js/myfile.js"></script>

     <title>demo</title>
  </head>
```

My file structure is as follows:

```
/path/to/project
    /public
        index.html
    /src/assets/js/myfile.js
```

When I add the javascript file, it seems to be interpreted as an HTML file, so in the console, I see the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

When I look at the source in the Chrome browser, I see that the js in interpreted as an HTML file.

Comment: seems like something that should be work. when you inspect the page, on the network tab, is the link to the javascript file okay?

Comment: Do you have that js folder explicitly in assets folder?
It's not mentioned in the file structure
 
../src/assets/js/myfile.js

Comment: There is a reason the folder is called Public, the page seems to be as root in there, so the src folder does not exist when you visit the page.